# Hybris HMC/HAC password reset

Tags: console, passwords, admin, reset, sap-commerce-cloud

I got a strange Problem with hmc/hac Passwords on Hybris.
somehow the Admin Password changed and nobody did that "I mean nobody wants to be the one".

Now I cannot log in and Need to reset this Password (for example into standardpassword) or over Database.

But I don't know how to do it.

Can anybody tell me how I can Change it within Shell Login or the Database?

Thanks in advance.
Fide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could update the users table, on my local Hybris passwords are not encrypted so i can simply run :

```
update users set passwd = 'nimda' where uniqueid = 'admin';
```

By default Hybris use a plain text encoder for employees, not for customer

```
default.password.encoder=core.plainTextEncoder
```

To activate MD5 password for employees you need to update your conf :

```
password.encoders=MD5=de.hybris.platform.persistence.security.SaltedMD5PasswordEncoder,*=de.hybris.platform.persistence.security.PlainTextPasswordEncoder
password.md5.salt=salt is salty
```

Then from the HMC you would be able to select Plain Text or MD% when you update a password.

Comment: thank you, that's it.


<EDIT>But why are passwords plain text in the database...</EDIT>

Comment: I have updated my answer, by default employees passwords are plain text